# Using Cmake with MPI and MPE

Tags: cmake, mpi

I have the following working CMakeList.txt as part of a bigger project:

```
# Project details
# ---------------
project(DAMZernike2016_mpi)

enable_language (C Fortran)

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../utils/" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)   # This is redundant (it has been previously checked), but convenient not to forget that MPI is necessary
add_definitions(${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS})
include_directories(${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH})
link_directories(${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})

# Fortran compiler flags
# ======================
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -g")

# Defines auxiliary containers with program names and directory with ancillary files
# ==================================================================================
set (DAMZernike_2016_mpi_PROGRAMS "DAMZernike-Jacobi_STO_mpi" "DAMZernike-Jacobi_GTO_mpi" )

set (DAMZernike_2016_mpi_EXECUTABLES "" )

set (ancillarydir "../DAMZernike2016" )

# Prepares Zernike-Jacobi_ckplm.F90 to be compiled without optimization (-O0)
# =============================================================================

set (ckplm_file "${ancillarydir}/Zernike-Jacobi_ckplm.F90")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${ckplm_file} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -O0) # Zernike-Jacobi_ckplm.F90 compiled without optimization to prevent long delay in compilation

# Ancillary files for libraries
# ===========================================================================

set (ancillaryfiles "${ancillarydir}/DAMZernike_2016_GLOBAL.F90" "${ancillarydir}/Zernike-Jacobi_ckplm.F90"  "${ancillarydir}/Zernike-Jacobi_paribkb.F90"  
"${ancillarydir}/Zernike-Jacobi_quadrat.f"  "${ancillarydir}/Zernike-Jacobi_stngexp.f"  
"${ancillarydir}/Zernike-Jacobi_subVABC.F90")

# Creates a library with modules
# ==============================
add_library(DAMZernikeGLOBAL_mpi_mods DAMZernike_2016_mpi_GLOBAL.F90 ${ancillaryfiles})

# Create binaries
# ===============
foreach (p ${DAMZernike_2016_mpi_PROGRAMS})
   add_executable(${p}.exe "${p}.F90")
   list (APPEND DAMZernike_2016_mpi_EXECUTABLES ${p}.exe )
endforeach (p)

# Links binaries to modules
# =========================
foreach (p ${DAMZernike_2016_mpi_EXECUTABLES})
   target_link_libraries("${p}" DAMZernikeGLOBAL_mpi_mods ${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})
   message("Adds ${p}")
endforeach (p)

# install executables and scripts
# ===============================
install (TARGETS ${DAMZernike_2016_mpi_EXECUTABLES} RUNTIME DESTINATION ".")      # Default installation directory: /usr/local/bin/
```

and I would like to modify it to link the targets with MPE (to be precise, with MPEFC), i.e. to cmake the equivalent to something like:

```
CC = /usr/local/bin/mpicc
LD = /usr/local/bin/mpefc
OBJ = ring.o
SRC = ring.c
EXEC = ring
CFLAGS = -g
LDFLAGS = -lm -mpilog

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): ${OBJ}
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $(EXEC)

ring.o: ${SRC}
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ring.c

clean:
    $(RM) ${OBJ} $(EXEC)
    $(RM) *.clog2 *.slog2
```

I have also picked a FindMPE.cmake from elsewhere (https://github.com/losalamos/CLAMR/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindMPE.cmake) to find whether MPE is installed. It works in my system and returns several variables like:

```
MPE_LOG_INCLUDE_PATH = /usr/local/include
MPE_LOG_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib64/libmpe_f2cmpi.a;/usr/lib64/liblmpe.a;/usr/local/lib/libmpe.a
MPE_COMPILER = /usr/local/bin/mpefc
```

among other.

I have made quite many unfruitful attempts and cannot find any suitable information in the net.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. Unfortunately cmake is not particularly good at using compiler/linker-wrappers. Usually you will have to use the appropriate `..._LIBRARIES`, `..._COMPILE_FLAGS`, `..._LINK_FLAGS` outputs of your find script. In your case this could look like:

```
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
find_package(MPE REQUIRED)

# Links binaries to modules
# =========================
foreach (p ${DAMZernike_2016_mpi_EXECUTABLES})
   target_link_libraries("${p}" DAMZernikeGLOBAL_mpi_mods ${MPE_LOG_LIBRARIES} ${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})
   set_target_properties("${p}" PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${MPE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
   set_target_properties("${p}" PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "${MPI_Fortran_LINK_FLAGS} ${MPE_LINK_FLAGS}"
   message("Adds ${p}")
endforeach (p)
```

Unfortunately I cannot test the answer. I'd advise to test for the existance of the `...FLAGS` variables.

Comment: I have tried your solution that looks simple and elegant, but unfortunately it does not work. The problem is that, even with this change, the resultant make is trying to link the objects with gfortran  and it should take mpifc as linker. (See the second and tenth lines, excluding blank lines,  in the Makefile that I quoted above as an example of what I want). I guess that the only piece lacking in your suggestion is how to carry out the change in the linker from gfortran to mpifc. I feel that if that question is answered, your suggestion will work.

Comment: Yes, this is expected. `mpifc` likely also uses `gfortran` internally, with a certain set of parameters. CMake tries to emulate those parameters to behave like `mpifc`. You will have to try to figure out how `mpifc`'s linker command differs from the one by CMake, e.g. by using `mpifc -show`. If all things fail you can also try to set `CMAKE_LINKER`, but I can't really recommend that.

Comment: I wrongly wrote mpifc instead of mpefc, but your suggestion seems to be fine in this case too. Running "/usr/local/bin/mpefc -show" I got: "mpefc: **** No profiling option is specifed! /usr/local/share/mpich2-install/bin/mpif90", and running "/usr/local/bin/mpefc -link-info" I got:   "gfortran -I/usr/local/share/mpich2-install/include -I/usr/local/share/mpich2-install/include -L/usr/local/share/mpich2-install/lib -lmpichf90 -lmpichf90 -lmpich -lopa -lmpl -lrt -lpthread"  Could you help me to implement this in the CMakeLists.txt? Thanks.

Comment: First, try to figure out what `FindMPE` figured for `MPE_LINK_FLAGS`, e.g. from `cmake -LAH`. Compare that to the parameters you got from "-link-info".

Answer (score 0):

Following Zulan's hints, and introducing a CACHE variable USE_MPE to control whether MPE is wanted or not, the following piece of code does the job:

```
# Links binaries to modules
# =========================
if(${USE_MPE})
    find_package(MPE)
    if (MPE_FOUND)
        message("Uses MPE for clog2 generation")
        set (MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS "-lfmpich -llmpe -lmpe -lpmpich" ${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS})
    endif (MPE_FOUND)
endif(${USE_MPE})
foreach (p ${DAMZernike_2016_mpi_EXECUTABLES})
    target_link_libraries("${p}" DAMZernikeGLOBAL_mpi_mods ${MPE_LOG_LIBRARIES} ${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})
    set_target_properties("${p}" PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${MPE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
    set_target_properties("${p}" PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "${MPI_Fortran_LINK_FLAGS} ${MPE_LINK_FLAGS}")
    message("Adds ${p}")
endforeach (p)
```